# Eclipse: Testing with Coverage throws java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I recently changed a couple of things in my Eclipse settings, mainly I upgraded the Java version from 8 to 15 and it took me a while to notice, but I cannot Test with Coverage anymore on any of my Projects as it throws a java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException with a gigantic StackTrace.

It also gives a PopUp Error, that says "No tests found with test runner 'Junit5'" Something, somewhere in the Java Librarys, Junit, or something must've broken, and I cannot figure out what it is. Normal Testing, Debug Testing and even Maven test all function normally with no indication of anything being wrong.

Here's the Junit Failure Trace:

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Locale provider adapter "CLDR"cannot be instantiated.
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:199)
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.findAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:287)
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:258)
at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:180)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2437)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.(Formatter.java:1956)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.(Formatter.java:1978)
at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3292)
at org.junit.runner.Description.formatDisplayName(Description.java:114)
at org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription(Description.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:121)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:401)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.configureRunner(RunnerBuilder.java:81)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:72)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:188)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleDataMetaInfo: Unable to load sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:584)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:856)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ModuleServicesLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1078)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:89)
at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'platform' attempted duplicate class definition for sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo. (sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo is in module jdk.localedata of loader 'platform')
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:784)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:705)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:586)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:546)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
... 38 more

And here the console StackTrace:

java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo.
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:94)
at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:784)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:705)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:586)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:546)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ModuleServicesLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1078)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:89)
at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:188)
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.findAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:287)
at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:258)
at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:180)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2437)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.(Formatter.java:1956)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.(Formatter.java:1978)
at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3292)
at org.junit.runner.Description.formatDisplayName(Description.java:114)
at org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription(Description.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:121)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:401)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.configureRunner(RunnerBuilder.java:81)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:72)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo.
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:159)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:109)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:92)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:195)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:176)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:162)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.classReaderFor(InstrSupport.java:280)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:75)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:107)
... 51 more

What I find weird about the Stack Trace is that seems to try and use Junit4, despite the fact that I've always used 5 both before and after my changes in Eclipse, but that's about the only thing I can read out of it.

Does someone know which setting in my Eclipse broke or help me decode the StackTrace?

Comment: Java 15 is not yet supported in code coverage. Use Java 13 or lower (Java 8 and 11 are the only ones with long time support) for code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Java 11 or java 1.8.281
JaCoCo version 0.8.5

Comment: Could you expand on why either of those version of Java or of JaCoCo might solve the issue in the question?

Comment: This was based on my trial and error testing. Still looking for the actual solutions